# How to fix Sonar issue "Remove this call to "wait" or move it into a "while" loop"?

Tags: java, multithreading, sonarqube

I am received a request to fix sonar issues in a legacy project, there is a code segment like this, every call to this function will be paused for 50ms:

```
synchronized(monitor) {

  [...]

  try {

    [...]

    Thread.sleep(config.getWaitTime()); // return 50
  } catch (SomeException e) {
    log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
  }

  [...]
}
```

First, sonar asked me to change `Thread.sleep()` to `wait()` so I change the try block to to:

```
try {

  [..]

  monitor.wait(config.getWaitTime());
} catch (SomeException e) {
  log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

Then, another issue appear : `Remove this call to "wait" or move it into a "while" loop` , I do not have much experience with multithreading, so I'm not sure my fix is correct:

```
boolean wait = true;
while (wait) {
  wait = false;
  monitor.wait(config.getWaitTime());
}
```

Is the above solution correct? If not, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the `while` appears helpless :

```
boolean wait = true;
while (wait) {
  wait = false;
  monitor.wait(config.getWaitTime());
}
```

The `while` statement around the `wait()` statement is designed to check that the `wait()` be re-invoked if the logical/function condition in the `while` is `true` but in your case it is never as you assign wait to  `false` as first statement of the while body.
The `while` is so helpless.
Here is the [`Object.wait(long)` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait-long-) associated to :

> A thread can also wake up without being notified, interrupted, or
>   timing out, a so-called spurious wakeup. While this will rarely occur
>   in practice, applications must guard against it by testing for the
>   condition that should have caused the thread to be awakened, and
>   continuing to wait if the condition is not satisfied.

As often I am not convinced at all of Sonar advises....
You could use a timer to check that the required time was elapsed in the while. But ugg.
I advise you to keep the Thread way that suits to your requirement.
Or if you want to make the tool API add helpless code. Of course I am joking : don't do that !

Comment: After a discussion with my tech leader, he agree that there may be high risks if changing already worked concurrent code and tell me ignore this issue.

Comment: And he is completely right. An additional reason to not do that.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Object#wait() Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(long))

> A thread can also wake up without being notified, interrupted, or
>   timing out, a so-called spurious wakeup. While this will rarely occur
>   in practice, applications must guard against it by testing for the
>   condition that should have caused the thread to be awakened, and
>   continuing to wait if the condition is not satisfied. **In other words,
>   waits should always occur in loops**, like this one:
>
> ```
>  synchronized (obj) {
>      while (<condition does not hold>)
>          obj.wait(timeout);
>      ... // Perform action appropriate to condition
>  }
> ```

Your loop doesn't look good, it should be something like:

```
while (wait) {
  monitor.wait(config.getWaitTime());
}
```

The `wait` variable must be set from elsewhere, when the wait condition is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

> sonar asked me to change Thread.sleep() to wait()

Just ignore sonar here. It is false positive alarm.